# Convert .tif to imagery layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, imagery, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

I'm trying to run this notebook in ArcGIS Pro: [https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/count-cars-in-aerial-imagery-using-deep-learning/#:~:text=imagery%20%3D%20gis.content.search(%22aerial*%22)](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/samples/count-cars-in-aerial-imagery-using-deep-learning/#:%7E:text=imagery%20%3D%20gis.content.search(%22aerial*%22))

I want to read my aerial imagery files (they're named aerial1, aerial2 etc.) which I have in .tif with this line of code:

```
imagery = gis.content.search("aerial*")
imagery
```

But it returns `[]`

I guess I need to have not .tif but some other file format. Which one? If it's imagery layer, how do I convert my .tif to it?

I haven't found anything on that.

I'm very new to ArcGIS

**EDIT**

I managed to load layers but after I run this code:

```
area1 = imagery[0]
area2 = imagery[1]
area3 = imagery[2]
area4 = imagery[3]

model = gis.content.search(
    "Car Detection-USA owner: esri_analytics", "Deep Learning Package", outside_org=True
)[0]

num_cars = {}
for i in range(len(imagery)):
    raster = imagery[i].layers[0]
    detected_cars = detect_objects(
        input_raster=raster,
        model=model,
        model_arguments={
            "padding": "100",
            "batch_size": "16",  # change batch size as per GPU specifications
            "threshold": "0.5",  # get detections greater than 50% confidence
            "return_bboxes": "False",
            "tile_size": "224",
        },
        output_name="detected_cars" + str(dt.now().microsecond),
        context={"processorType": "GPU", "cellSize": 1},
    )  # cell size is based on imagery resolution
    num_cars[area1.name] = len(detected_cars.layers[0].query(as_df=True))
```

I have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [15]:
Line 3:     raster = imagery[i].layers[0]

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in __getattribute__:
Line 13158: if self["layers"] == None or self["layers"] == []:

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in __getitem__:
Line 13204: return dict.__getitem__(self, k)

KeyError: 'layers'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

it is telling you that the return is empty.
Therefore it's printing an empty list.

To troubleshoot this I would try to answer these questions:

1. Do you have any raster datasets in your "home" directory in ArcGIS online?
2. Did the authentication to your ArcGIS Online Account work successfully?